# openssl is not recognized as an internal or external command when adding FacebookSDK

Tags: android, facebook

I want to add Facebook sdk into my android application. I am following [this tutorial.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)

I am stuck at this point:

Firstly, to generate your key hash on your local computer, run Java's keytool utility (which should be on your console's path) against the Android debug keystore. This is, by default, in your home `.android directory`). On OS X, run:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

which tells me that `:openssl` is not recognized as an internal or external command

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it, I have to write the full path for debug.keystore and for openssl :)